# How to addChild with custom name in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

in as2 i had this code:

```
symback.attachMovie("" + syms, "s_" + s);
```

and later i can change it's position like this:

```
symback["s_" + s]._y = Ypos;
```

i tried this but recieve error (A term is undefined and has no properties):

```
symback["s_" + s].addChild(new syms());
```

while this works:

```
symback.addChild(new ImeSimbola());
```

but i can't access it's position later...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access children of a certain container if you know their names.

```
var aSym:DisplayObject;

aSym = new ImeSimbola;
aSym.name = "s_" + s;

symback.addChild(aSym);
```

Then.

```
aSym = symback.getChildByName("s_" + s);
aSym.y = yPos;
```

Comment: That is what i need. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to a variable before adding it to the stage:

```
var newChild = new ImeSimbola();
symback.addChild(newChild);
newChild._y = Ypos;
```

Comment: Hi,tried that, problem is when trying to add "symback["s_" + s]"

Comment: Question is how to make this in as3: 
symback.attachMovie("" + syms, "s_" + s);

Comment: Please explain where your variables come from. What's `s` and `syms`, and why do you want that syntax specifically?

Comment: i pass this variables when calling function - function setSymbol(s, syms), i call it by: setSymbol(3, s3)